# Change the NavigationFrame Content on Button Click in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, expression-blend

I am new to WPF. 
I went through many questions on StackOverFlow regarding changing the contents of the frame,but I couldnt find an appropriate one.

Here is the scenario.
I have a window having a grid. The grid is splitted up into two parts.
On Left Hand Grid I have got Tile Layout having Tiles. and On Right Hand side I have got Navigation Frame. Left Hand Side Grid is fixed.
When I click on Left Hand Grid Tiles I need to display or change the Navigation Frame on clicking different tiles.
How do I achieve NavigationFrame Content change on button Click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no NavigationFrame
I assume you mean a regular frame

```
Frame1.Navigate(new Page1());
```

Or you can create your Pages in advance

A frame holds a Page
Are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: Ok thanks. Let me try this one...If it doesnt work then i shall get back to you..